# Android services lifecycle

Tags: android, android-service

I have 4 services A B C and D. I have made A running in a loop and when the start of its initialization, i set alarm manager intent in my A service to start B C and D services every few minutes. So A keeps running, and B,C and D wake up every few minutes complete their tasks and go to sleep. Now I want A also to be woken up by Alarm Manager.

How can I do it?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Make A a sticky service with a TimerTask running in it every few minutes.

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) 
{

    Timer timer  =  new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

        public void run() 
        {
               // start B, C, D
        }

    }, 20000, 60000);  // every 60 seconds


    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Comment: Can you help me understand how does it work? Can I use the timer anywhere else instead of the onStartCommand. This is my current code in A. From onStartcommand it goes to onHandleIntent and from there i  kick off the other services. How can I use it here?                  @Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
 super.onCreate();
 super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
 return START_STICKY;
}

Answer (score 0):

Set up a [`BroadcastReceiver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) to get alarm events from the OS.  Then, register an alarm at your desired periodicy with the [`AlarmManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html).  When your receiver gets the alarm from the OS, you can fire off the intents for your four `Service`s.

Set up the `BroadcastReceiver` in the `onCreate()` method of your launcher `Activity` and you should be good to go!